# SQL query to count duplicate instances with a common denominator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a little help on working this out using SQL

sample data

```
+------+---+---+
|height|age|sex|
+------+---+---+
|150   |21 |m  |
+------+---+---+
|160   |22 |f  |
+------+---+---+
|170   |19 |m  |
+------+---+---+
|150   |30 |m  |
+------+---+---+
|140   |44 |f  |
+------+---+---+
|150   |33 |m  |
+------+---+---+
|170   |21 |m  |
+------+---+---+
```

I need a total count of instances when there is more than one person with the same height and one of them is 21?

So the answer here should be 2

Comment: `instances` == `records`? If so, I don't understand what's hard in the query. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

```
select height, count(*)
from your_table
group by height
having count(*) > 1
and sum(case when age = 21 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

You probably want the pairs to have both genders. Then add

```
and count(distinct sex) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE age = 21 AND height IN 
    (SELECT height FROM Table WHERE age <> 21);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked as expected